# cron GAE service permisions

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, google-api-java-client, cron-task

I have GAE application. I have CRON service. It fires **www.example.appspot.com/cron/schedule** servlet.

PROBLEM:
Everyone have access to this servlet. I dont want to have everyone access to this servlet. I need to fire that servlet only cron.

In the other word I need: **servlet access permission only for cron**

I do something like that:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>cron</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/cron/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

every servlet in **/cron/** cant be fire eccept admin (If I deploy app, app engine is admin). So is this sulution? what do you think? Am I correct?

[that is link](http://ltv-checker.appspot.com/cron/PDValidation)

Comment: yes your correct, that's exactly how you do it. you can test this of course by trying to hit the url as a non admin user - you should get a 403

Comment: No, I don't have error 403 :(

Comment: it's my [link](http://ltv-checker.appspot.com/cron/PDValidation) it's redirect to another pages.... I dont understand why

Comment: it's redirecting to http://ltv-checker.appspot.com/_ah/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/logIn.jsp. you must have a redirect loop somewhere in your config or code?

Comment: no. no.  I only have  another servlet on <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>. This servlet redirects page to www.example.appspot.com/test/login.jsp (if user is not in session).

but whay it is redirected on this servlet? I don't undestand. :( Not I'm not at the computer. I will see again tomorow.

Comment: because of I have <role-name>admin</role-name>, it tries to find login page. In localhost it redirects to "/_ah/login?", and in deployed app, it cant find the login page migh be.